# Firebase auth with mobile code (phone auth) sign in with code expired

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase phone auth when correctly implemented gives the developer a verification code which must be typed to confirm the mobile phone.

When you check the `verificationID` that Firebase provides plus the verification code, you get verified and consequently logged in.

Using this method, a user can confirm the code and login:

```
let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
    withVerificationID: verificationID,
    verificationCode: verificationCode)*

PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(self.phoneNum.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
    UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVID")
}
```

Now, you need the verification code sent to login.

I get the `verificationID` and save it to `UserDefaults`.

But after that, when the code expires I can't proceed with the login because it asks me again for another verification code.

How can I make a login using only the `verificationID` generated by firebase?

I tried the method:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVID") ?? "")
```

but firebase says that the authentication token is invalid.

I don't know which method I can use to make the login using only the token provided by firebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to call the method to verify mobile number. Once mobile number verified you will get `OTP` on verified mobile number. So write following method to verify mobile number.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
  if let error = error {
     // Show alert here
     return
  }
  // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
  // Here your can store your verificationID in user default and later used for sign in. Or pass this verification id to your next view controller for OTP verification.
    UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
}
```

Next in `OTP` verification screen when user enter `OTP` you can create following credentials to sign in.

`verificationId` - we have stored in UserDefault
`verificationCode` - OTP which are available though mobile message.

```
// Get verification Id from User Default
let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID")

let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
    withVerificationID: verificationID,
    verificationCode: verificationCode)
```

Now call signing method.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
  if let error = error {
    // ...
    return
  }
  // User is signed in
  // Here sign in completed.
  }
}
```

Here Sign in completed, now you can navigate to screen which will open after successfully login.

To set home screen when application re-open and your want to set directly home screen write following code.

```
func setInitialViewController() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        // setup home screen
    } else {
        //Setup login screen
    }
}
```

And call the above method from AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Dear Paul Marshal. Thanks for the prompt answer. That is exactly what I did. The problem is, after one day the OTP seems to expire and then I got this error: "The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.,

Comment: @carlosaugusto, Yes u r right. OTP is expired due to not valid. OTP may be valid upto 30-45 minute from you receive. After that it will expire and you need new OTP. This is not an issues.

Comment: I see Paul Marshal, but, how can I keep a user logged in firebase using this mobile auth?

Comment: Means, Once login completed you want to open home screen instead of login screen ???

Comment: yes Paul, for example, after the user confirm the mobile code, the user will automatically signIn every time the user opens the application. And Log inside the firebase database

Comment: Pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that exactly what I did. The problem is, after some minutes or day, when I try to sign in using this same method:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
```

Firebase returns telling that the code used inside the credential has expired:

Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17051 "The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again., error_name=ERROR_SESSION_EXPIRED}

Comment: Yes, That is right. After some time OTP will expired due to security purpose.

Comment: But, It got expired within one minute. And I suppose this login should be like the WhatsApp phone verification. Am I wrong?

Comment: No. You r not wrong. I have implemented same thing in my project. It's working fine. There are something missing in project setup or in code.

Answer (score 0):

Phone Authentication and get OTP for given mobile number and verify that OTP

```
Auth.auth().settings!.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = false
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(textfieldPhoneNumber.text!,uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID ?? "",verificationCode: self.verificationcode)
            Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authData, error) in
                if ((error) != nil) {
                    return
                }
                if let user  = authData!.user as? User {
                    authData!.user.getIDToken(completion: { user, error in })
                    if error != nil {
                        return
                    }
                    let uid = user.uid
                    let RefereshToken = user.refreshToken
                    let token = user.phoneNumber
                    print(uid)
                    print(RefereshToken as Any)
                    print(token as Any)
                }

                print(User.self as Any)

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello M.srinivasan, please can you format your code so that horizontal scrollbar in code part disappears ? Normally, for new users, I do that myself but I don't know your programming language. I don't know what is line continuation character if exits ! It is always better for other to read well formatted code :-)